# Радость и веселье

Tags: плеоназм

В принципе, понятия схожие и даже идентичные. Но вот насколько они взаимозаменяемы? Вообще, где разница между понятиями "радость" и "веселье"?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если очень кратко, "радость" - событие, "веселье" - состояние. 
Обычно первое влечет второе. Но может случиться и наоборот.

Answer (score 2):

Понятия схожие, но из разных плоскостей. Радость – это эмоция, веселье – это состояние. Возможно, приведу не слишком корректный пример, но все же: ненависть и вражда. Ненависть – это ваша эмоция по отношению к кому-то, вражда – это состояние, в котором вы с ним находитесь.

Answer (score 2):

Радость - от решения проблемы, а веселье - игнорирование проблемы. Радость созидательна, она открывает новые возможности для радости же. За веселье всегда приходится расплачиваться.